# Unity Alternatives to "Snapshots" Controls with Resonance Audio

Tags: unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

I'm wondering what other solutions people are using to control volume and activation of various Resonance Audio Sources in Unity.

I'm working on a mobile VR experience in Unity with interactible elements (looping audio until player triggers next step) and linear movement of the player between different-sounding spaces in one scene.

I've resorted to using the Animation features on the Timeline to control how to turn Audio Sources on and off and setting volumes, as Snapshots and other audio controls are ignored in the Resonance Mixer.

I'd love to hear how other Resonance users are controlling their audio!

Thanks,
Anna